# I want to use subscription in GraphQL with .net framework 4.62 Is is possible with hotchocolate package?

Tags: .net, graphql, hotchocolate

I saw that in GraphQL .NET the subscription is not working. Only with .NET core.
Do you know if it possible with hotchocolate package of graphQL? I didn't find anything specific on it.

Comment: Did you even look at the dependencies for [the Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HotChocolate)?

Answer (score 1):

subscription itself are available for both .Net Framework and .Net Core.

But we only have implemented the Apollo subscription protocol for web sockets on .Net core.

If there is demand for it we could look into implementing it for Owin as well.

If you want to do it on your own you can do so, the query engine will return a response stream which can be observed.